# Warning when using a blacklisted tag - is it customizable?

Tags: support, warning, blocked-tags

I suppose that when a user tries to submit question with a blacklisted tag, he gets warning of this type:

> sorry, the 'example-tag' tag is not allowed.

(I don't know this for sure, but I guess this is the case, since this is what I get when I try to submit a question with tags which I suspect to be blacklisted. If the precise text of warning is documented somewhere, I would be grateful for this information.)

I would like to know whether this text can be customized, i.e., if some tags is blacklisted, whether it is possible to add some explanation to the error message. (E.g. why this tag is not allowed, what tags should be used instead.)

One possible situation when having something like this could be useful is the situation described in this feature request at meta.math.SE: [Disambiguation pseudo-tags](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4472/disambiguation-pseudo-tags). (But I have no doubt similar needs arise at other SE sites, too.)

Comment: Usually you can search for "example-tag" here on Meta and find a whole discussion about why it should be blacklisted. A large majority of tags don't get blacklisted without a good Meta discussion advocating why the tag is so horrible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now there is a new feature, which allows adding some message when blacklisting. For more details see this post, which is now marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed): [Allow adding a specific message / guidance to blacklists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217915/allow-adding-a-specific-message-guidance-to-blacklists)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that this text is not customizable.

Blacklisting a tag is a manual and last-ditch effort to curb the use of tags which are extremely detrimental to a site; the focus when putting the tag on the blacklist is not to explain why, but to stop its use.

Comment: Judging by [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16310/rename-exercises-and-solutions-tag-or-completely-remove-it/16381#16381) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217915/allow-adding-a-specific-message-guidance-to-blacklists), it seems that now it is possible to add customizable message to blacklisted words/tags.

Comment: @Martin better post new answer quoting those others posts to make it clear the message can be customized.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I have posted a separate answer, per your recommendation.