# Blacklist warnings aren't shown when editing comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, blocklist

A while back, we added the ability to [attach specific guidance to blacklisted terms.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217915/allow-adding-a-specific-message-guidance-to-blacklists)

This works for comments as well:

[image]

But it doesn't work if you're adding the blacklisted term as an *edit* to a comment:

[image]

This can [lead to confusion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284796/whats-wrong-with-this-comment) in cases where the guidance is essential to understanding the block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the Shog9 has spoken and it has been done.  How's that for authority?  It will be shipped in the next build.

Comment: Stack Exchange Deity ™